# NSOperation finished KVO is sent on main thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an asynchronous `NSOperation` in my app that executes an asynchronous method with a callback block that by default is executed on the main thread:

```
- (void)start {
    self.executing = YES;
    [self.object doSomethingWithCallback:^{
        // this block is by default executed on main thread
        self.finished = YES;
    }];
}
```

The problem with this seems to be that the KVO notification for `finished` is sent on the main thread so my `NSOperationQueue` will never know that the operation is finished. 
How can I make sure that the callback is executed on the same thread as the operation?

Should I create my own dispatch queue and set `NSOperationQueue.underlayingQueue` and then make sure that the callback is executed on that?

Are there any downsides with that approach?

Is there any better way?